# Running IE8 32 bit on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Running IE8 32 bit on Windows 7 64 bit ... possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows 7 64-bit comes out-of-the-box with Internet Explorer 8 in both 32-bit and 64-bit. Unless you explicitly launch IE8 64-bit, you're probably running the 32-bit version.

By default, IE8 32-bit automatically runs when you start the browser from any one of the following locations:

- The Quick Launch toolbar
- The desktop
- The Start menu
- A hyperlink or a file type that is associated with Internet Explorer

If you want to see which version is currently running, check the Help -> About Internet Explorer window. The 64-bit version will note that it's the 64-bit version.

The main difference between the two is that IE8 64-bit only runs native 64-bit ActiveX controls, and IE8 32-bit only runs native 32-bit ActiveX controls. This means that plugins like Flash that are 32-bit will *only* work in the 32-bit Internet Explorer ([see Adobe's KB on the subject](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/6b3af6c9.html)).

From [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896457):

> The differences between the 32-bit and
>   64-bit versions of Internet Explorer
>   can affect toolbar add-ins and
>   Microsoft ActiveX controls. For
>   example, 32-bit toolbar add-ins do not
>   work in the 64-bit version of Internet
>   Explorer. These add-ins include the
>   MSN toolbar, the AOL toolbar, the eBay
>   toolbar, and the Google toolbar. You
>   can install 32-bit toolbars in the
>   32-bit version of Internet Explorer.
>   However, the 32-bit toolbars will not
>   appear in the 64-bit version of
>   Internet Explorer.
>
> For example, when you start the Setup
>   program for the 32-bit Google toolbar
>   in the 64-bit version of Internet
>   Explorer, the Google Setup program
>   closes the 64-bit Internet Explorer
>   window. The Google Setup program opens
>   a new 32-bit Internet Explorer window
>   when setup is completed. The Google
>   toolbar appears in the 32-bit version
>   of Internet Explorer, and the toolbar
>   works correctly. The 32-bit Google
>   toolbar is not installed in the 64-bit
>   version of Internet Explorer.
>
> By design, the 64-bit version of
>   Internet Explorer cannot host 32-bit
>   ActiveX controls. Additionally, the
>   32-bit version of Internet Explorer
>   cannot host 64-bit ActiveX controls.

Comment: I did not know that some ActiveX plugins require IE8-32bit to run correctly. I spent two hours searching and screwing around with Security Controls in IE to no avail (I'm a Firefox user). And Paul is right, the IE8-64bit version is the default for Windows7. However, for me 'All Programs' had two shortcuts for IE: IE and IE (64bit). I'm guessing you can figure out which one is the 32bit version. I also found the 32 bit version of IE8 in the same place as Paul, in case your 'All Programs' list doesn't show both